# Swift2 to Swift3 error - Cannot assign value of type 'NSDictionary?' to type 'AddressModel'

Tags: swift3, nsdictionary

Moving an app from Swift2 to Swift3 and I've hit an error that I've been unable to fix after trying several different suggestions.

```
lazy var address: AddressModel? = {
        [unowned self] in
        var dict = self.getpayloadDict()

        var model: AddressModel
        model = dict
        return model
        }()
```

model = dict throws Cannot assign value of type 'NSDictionary?' to type 'AddressModel'

The AddressModel . . .

```
class AddressModel: Deserializable {
    var City: String?
    var State: String?
    var PostalCode: String?    

    required init(data: [String: AnyObject]) {
        City = data["City"] as! String?
        State = data["State"] as! String?
        PostalCode = data["PostalCode"] as! String?
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is supposed to occur also in Swift 2. It's pretty clear: `getpayloadDict()` returns a dictionary which doesn't match `AddressModel`.

You might create an `AddressModel` instance from the dictionary

```
lazy var address: AddressModel? = { // this closure does not cause a retain cycle
    let dict = self.getpayloadDict()
    return AddressModel(data: dict)
}()
```

Side note:

`as! String?` (force unwrap an optional to an optional) is horrible syntax. Use regular conditional downcast `as? String`. And please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thank you - I was surprised this worked in Swift2 as well as it looked like it should error out there too. Creating the AddressModel instance in the dictionary worked great!